# Parse text file with regular columns but no separators

Tags: r, text, substring, readline, read.table

text data:

```
> dput(AUDIT)
c("0FL/SEG   ACCOUNT NUMBER   SECURITY NUMBER             DATE     TIME     TASK   COMMND  MODE   USERID  OPER TERM   MEMO   TRANS  PAGE", 
" -------  ---------------  ------------------------  -------- -------- -------- ------ ------ -------- ---- ---- -------- ------ ----", 
" ", " SD BOND                   00330596                  13/09/17 11465277    30343 SCT3   CHANGE A602982                               1", 
" SD BOND                   00338171                  13/09/17 09413755    33369 SCT3   CHANGE A602982                               2", 
" SD BOND                   00358813                  13/09/17 09410336    30601 SCT3   CHANGE A602982                               4", 
" SD BOND                   00367251                  13/09/17 11453785    29908 SCT3   CHANGE A602982                               5", 
"\\n", "", "")
>
```

I am currently using the following lines to parse the file into a table. I do so by going line by line and selecting text substrings:

```
IO_extract <- data.frame()
for (i in 4:7) {

      FL_SEG <- substr(AUDIT[i], 2, 8)
      ACC_NO <- substr(AUDIT[i], 11, 25)
      SEC_ID <- substr(AUDIT[i], 28, 35)
      DATE   <- substr(AUDIT[i], 54, 61)
      TIME   <- substr(AUDIT[i], 63, 70)
      TASK   <- substr(AUDIT[i], 72, 79)
      SCREEN <- substr(AUDIT[i], 81, 86)
      ACTION <- substr(AUDIT[i], 88, 93)
      A_NUMB <- substr(AUDIT[i], 95, 101)

output <- t(as.matrix(c(FL_SEG, ACC_NO, SEC_ID, DATE, TIME, TASK, SCREEN, ACTION, A_NUMB)))
colnames(output) <- c("FL_SEG", "ACC_NO", "SEC_ID", "DATE", "TIME", "TASK", "SCREEN", "ACTION", "A_NUMB")
IO_extract <- rbind(IO_extract, output)

}
```

does someone have a simpler way I can do this?

Comment: This looks like a fixed width file. Look at `?read.fwf` or `?readr::read_fwf`